# Convert mysqli to pdo bind_all

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

here is my current code

```
function getUserDetails($username=NULL, $id=NULL) {
    if($username!=NULL) {
        $column = "user_name";
        $data = $username;
    }
    elseif($id!=NULL) {
        $column = "id";
        $data = $id;
    }

    global $db;

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT id, username, permissions, forename, surname, password, email, courseid, choiceid, lastlogin, active FROM users WHERE $column = :column");
    $query->bindParam(":column", $data);
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result ($id, $username, $permissions, $forename, $surname, $password, $email, $courseid, $choiceid, $lastlogin, $active);
    while ($query->fetch()){
        $row = array('id' => $id, 'userlevel' => $permissions, 'username' => $username, 'forename' => $forename, 'surname' => $surname, 'password' => $password, 'email' => $email, 'courseId' => $courseid, 'choiceId' => $choiceId, 'lastlogin' => $lastlogin, 'active'=> $active);
    }
    return ($row);
}
```

I have been trying to convert this to pdo, as I've found out bind_result doesn't work with pdo - could anyone help me as to what I should be doing?

I've read arround that I should be using fetch? But i'm getting really confused.

[edit]

ive tried this:

```
function getUserDetails($username=NULL,$id=NULL) {
    if($username!=NULL) {
        $column = "user_name";
        $data = $username;
    }
    elseif($id!=NULL) {
        $column = "id";
        $data = $id;
    }

    global $db;

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT id, username, permissions, forename, surname, password, email, courseid, choiceid, lastlogin, active FROM users WHERE $column = :column");
    $query->bindParam(":column", $data);
    $query->execute();

    $results = array();
    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
        $results[] = $row;
    }

    return ($results);
}
```

is this a step in the right direction ?

[edit2]

updated my code to this:

```
function getUserDetails($username) {
    global $db;

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username");
    $query->bindParam(":username", $username);
    return $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

$username = 'uname';
$result = getUserDetails($username);
print_r($result);
```

however it prints nothing. the username definitely exists.

---

ive tried a test database with some dummy data

```
$data = '2';
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = :id");
$sth->bindParam(":id", $data);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

im trying to figure out how i access what is in the printed array:
the array comes out as

```
Array ( [Id] => 2 [Name] => tom )
```

how do i (for example) do

```
$name = $result['name'];    //line 67
```

when i try that code i get

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in <directory>\test.php on line 67
```

---

Figured it out!

```
function getUserDetails($username) {
    global $db;

    $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT id, username, permissions, forename, surname, password, email, courseid, choiceid, lastlogin, active FROM users WHERE username = :username");
    $sth->bindParam(":username", $username);
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $result;
}


$username = 'un';
$userdetails = getUserDetails($username);
echo $userdetails['forename'];
```

and it gives me the correct answer!
thanks for your help

Comment: 1. **you need to use connect options form the tag wiki I linked to** in my answer to get the errors. 2. You need to make you mind about field name. if it's `user_name`, `username`, `Name` or `name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YES!
It's great step in the right direction.
As you can see, **mysqli is absolutely unusable with prepared statements**, both in binding placeholders **and** returning results.
while PDO can solve your problem using dramatically less code.
You don't need useless bind with PDO at all - just get all results with fetchAll():

```
function getUserDetails($username=NULL,$id=NULL) {
    if ($username) {
        $column = "user_name";
        $data = $username;
    } elseif($id) {
        $column = "id";
        $data = $id;
    } else {
        return;
    }
    global $db;

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE $column = ?");
    $query->execute(array($data));
    return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

But wait. Why do you want to return an array if it's users details? 
It will add just useless dimension to the returned array. 
For this very case make it

```
    return $query->fetch();
```

instead of fetchAll().
But then you need many rows - use this latter method.
On other methods and useful connect options refer to the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

Comment: how would i then call the result? i'm trying to get a result via "$userdetails = getUserDetails($username); $echo $userdetails['forename'];"

Comment: i updated my code to :
function getUserDetails($username) {
    global $db;

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username");
 $query->bindParam(":username", $username);
    return $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

$username = 'uname';
$result = getUserDetails($username);
print_r($result);

but when i try to print the result its empty [ EDIT ] added the code to my original question for easier reading

Comment: Thanks for your help! I figured it out! :D